# Installing programs in custom directory Win Server 2008 R2 - problems setting as default applcation

Tags: windows, file-association

For legacy reasons at work, we are trying to install applications on Windows 2008 R2, not in program files (or program files (x86)) but in a Development Applcations folder.

This is working fine in running the applications, however we are finding it difficult now to set these apps as default programs for the required extensions, Windows is basically ignoring the attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that I had previously installed the required application in Program Files (x86) then uninstalled it.

When I reinstalled it in my custom Program Files, the Application File Type was still pointing to Program Files (x86).

Using [FileTypeMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) (as [referenced from here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/81007-file-association-problem.html)), I pointed it to the correct exe, and the application was functionally available to use as a default application.